# Finding Mean Values in a Column by Intervals

Tags: r, mean

I'm tracking violent events around a treatment-week to see if the treatment has an effect on the event count around it. The table is broken into country-week and records violent events for most countries between 1989-2019. It is similar to this, but with a total of approx. 120 countries and 70k rows:

```
    Country  Year  Week  Event_Count  Treatment
    -------  ----  ----  -----------  ---------
    Angola   1995  33    3            NA
    Angola   1995  34    2            NA
    Angola   1995  35    3            NA
    Angola   1995  36    0            NA
    Angola   1995  37    4            1
    Angola   1995  38    1            NA
    Angola   1995  39    0            NA
    Angola   1995  40    2            NA
    Angola   1995  41    3            NA
```

I'd like to find the average weekly event count broken into four-week intervals around the treatment week (in this case, week 37 denoted by the "1" in the Treatment column) up until twelve weeks in both directions. In other words, weeks -1 to -4 would be 2 events as this is the average weekly event count for weeks 33 thru 36. Week 0 (in this case, week 37) would be 4. Weeks 1 to 4 (38 thru 41) would be 1.5. And weeks -5 to -8 (weeks 29 to 32), 5 to 8 (42 to 45), -9 to -12 (25 to 28), and 9 to 12 (46 to 49) would be the average weekly values within their respective bins. I'm using a regression discontinuity design, so I'd like to do the same thing for countries that just missed receiving the treatment, denoted by "0" in the treatment column. All other values in the treatment column are "NA".
I was thinking about coding like this:

```
    aggregate(df[row_interval, column_interval], list(df$Country), mean)
```

but since I'll be looking at several treatment weeks within the same country, and the treatment weeks change regularly (e.g., Angola, 1995 Week 37; Algeria, 1998 Week 12, etc.), this wouldn't work. Ideally, I'd like to place the output for treatments of both "0" and "1" in the same row as the treatment week. For example:

```
    Country Year Week Event_Count Treatment -12to-9 -8to-5 -4to-1 0 1to4 5to8 9to12
    ------- ---- ---- ----------- --------- ------- ------ ------ - ---- ---- -----
    Algeria 2002  14     4           0         3      0.5    1    4  2    5    2
```

I'm trying to put the outputs for similar weeks in the same column, regardless of receiving "0" or "1" for treatment. E.g., all values for weeks 1 to 4 after the treatment would fall under the "1to4" column.

Thank you in advance for your help! I'm fairly new to stack and r, so I apologize for any confusion.

Comment: Do you only need -12~+12?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I write longer data that contains total 25 weeks.

```
Country  Year  Week Event_Count Treatment
   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 Angola   1995    25           3        NA
 2 Angola   1995    26           2        NA
 3 Angola   1995    27           4        NA
 4 Angola   1995    28           1        NA
 5 Angola   1995    29           0        NA
 6 Angola   1995    30           4        NA
 7 Angola   1995    31           1        NA
 8 Angola   1995    32           0        NA
 9 Angola   1995    33           3        NA
10 Angola   1995    34           2        NA
# ... with 15 more rows
```

Same as your example, Week 37 has `Treatment`.
Define function `gola` as,

```
gola <- function(df) {
  idx <- which(!is.na(df$Treatment))
  res <- c()
  for (i in idx){
    trt <- df$Event_Count
    x.3 <- mean(trt[(i-12):(i-9)])
    x.2 <- mean(trt[(i-8):(i-5)])
    x.1 <- mean(trt[(i-4):(i-1)])
    x <- trt[i]
    x1 <- mean(trt[(i+1):(i+4)])
    x2 <- mean(trt[(i+5):(i+8)])
    x3 <- mean(trt[(i+9):(i+12)])
    res <- rbind(res,c(x.3, x.2, x.1, x, x1, x2, x3))
    
  }
  colnames(res) <- c("_12to_9", "_8to_5", "_4to_1", "0", "1to4", "5to8", "9to12")
  res <- cbind(df[idx,], res)
  return(res) 
}
```

Then, `gola(df)` will return

```
  Country Year Week Event_Count Treatment _12to_9 _8to_5 _4to_1 0 1to4 5to8 9to12
1  Angola 1995   37           4         1     2.5   1.25      2 4  1.5    2  1.75
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! It works! I would up your score 100 points if I could! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is what I got. I do not have your actual data. So, I created my own sample data, which would be similar to yours. My idea may/may not work for you depending on your actual data. But I think the idea has some essence to tackle your case. The key point is, I think, how you generate sub group indices. You have a base row, where you have either 0, 1 or NA in Treatment. (In my example, I just used 1. You need to think about cases where you do not have any 1 or 0 in Treatment.) Basically, I wanted to identify row numbers that I can use as flags to create subgroups. When you want to identify such rows, you need to think when row numbers are smaller/larger than the base row or not. You see this in the first case_when(). The second case_when() handles generating group numbers. After this, the job seems pretty straightforward. I hope this helps you to some extent.

```
group_by(mydf, Country) %>%
  mutate(group = 1:n(),
         group = case_when(row_number() %in% (which(Treatment == 1) + 
                                       (4 * 1:floor(length(group[which(Treatment == 1):n()]) / 4)) + 1) ~
                         TRUE,
                  row_number() %in% (which(Treatment == 1) - 
                                            (4 * 1:floor(length(group[1:which(Treatment == 1)]) / 4)) - 1) ~
                         TRUE,
                  row_number() == which(Treatment == 1) ~ TRUE,
                         TRUE ~ FALSE),
         group = case_when(row_number() < which(Treatment == 1) ~
                             cumsum(c(T, diff(group) == -1)),
                           row_number() > which(Treatment == 1) ~
                             cumsum(c(F, diff(group) == 1)) + as.integer(100),
                           TRUE ~ as.integer(100))) %>% 
 group_by(group, .add = TRUE) %>% 
 summarize(year = first(Year),
           week = paste(first(Week), last(Week), sep = "-"),
           average = mean(Event_Count, rm.na = TRUE)) %>% 
 select(-group)

#  Country    year week  average
#   <chr>     <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
# 1 Argentina  1995 24-24    4   
# 2 Argentina  1995 25-28    5   
# 3 Argentina  1995 29-32    7.25
# 4 Argentina  1995 33-36    7.75
# 5 Argentina  1995 37-37    8   
# 6 Argentina  1995 38-41    3.5 
# 7 Argentina  1995 42-45    7.253
# 8 Argentina  1995 46-49    5.25
# 9 Argentina  1995 50-50    9   
#10 Brazil     1995 24-24    4   
#11 Brazil     1995 25-28    5   
#12 Brazil     1995 29-32    6   
#13 Brazil     1995 33-36    7.5 
#14 Brazil     1995 37-37    7   
#15 Brazil     1995 38-41    6.5 
#16 Brazil     1995 42-45    4   
#17 Brazil     1995 46-49    6.5 
#18 Brazil     1995 50-50   10
```

**DATA**

```
set.seed(111)
mydf <- data.frame(Country = rep(c("Argentina", "Brazil"), each = 27),
                   Year = rep(1995, times = 54),
                   Week = rep(c(24:50), times = 2),
                   Event_Count = sample.int(n = 10, size = 54, replace = TRUE),
                   Treatment = rep(c(rep(NA, times = 13), 1, rep(NA, times = 13)), times = 2))
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks so much for figuring this out -- I really appreciate it!!

Comment: @DylanForrester I’m glad to hear that. When your cases are done, can you close them by clicking the tick you can find near up/down vote? Choose whichever works for you best. In this way, future readers of your post can be sure that any solutions you chose works. The reader will receive benefits.